# How to make Existing webpages which are working good in IE7 to work in IE11?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, x-ua-compatible

I've been searching for permanent solution to make the existing pages(ASP.Net) which are working perfect in IE7 to work in IE11 as well. I've seen some solutions to manipulate meta tag.

**meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"**

could someone please provide some real solutions to fix these problems?

Right now i see too many CSS Issues & Javascript errors in IE11 which worked good in IE7.

It would be really helpful it someone provides a solution without CSS Hacks or manipulating content of meta tag. I'm not targeting my website to be cross browser but it atleast should work in Internet explorer irrespective of its version.

I saw below references from MSDN: but it didn't give any solution to make websites render in all versions of IE, it was addressing issues about legacy browser.

**https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee318404.aspx**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's not going to be as easy as editing a meta tag. You're going to have to rewrite the broken parts of the page.

Comment: The solution would be to fix the CSS and JavaScript errors.

Comment: The `x-ua-compatible` meta tag is there for this very purpose; set the content to `IE=EmulateIE7` for starters. After that, let's talk about the specific things that weren't resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track; but you took a violent turn and derailed with that meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

The above tag instructs the browser to use the *latest* features possible. This is the exact opposite of what you want if you're seeking to support IE 7. Instead, set it to *emulate* IE 7:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

This should take care of many problems, but it may not resolve all of them. If you're looking to repair an intranet application or some other corporate utility, I would encourage you to look into [Enterprise Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/02/stay-up-to-date-with-enterprise-mode-for-internet-explorer-11.aspx), which is a higher-fidelity emulation of Internet Explorer 8.

If, even after setting the `x-ua-compatible` meta tag (or header) you are still seeing some errors, please ask specific questions regarding those and I'm sure myself (and the greater community) will be more than happy to assist.

Note that the above approach (meta-tag/header) is intended only as a temporary solution. The *real solution* is to update your code and bring the application current.

Comment: Yeah i too observed that using x-ua-compatible in meta tag is not reliable approach..

Ref: https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible

I'm ready to update the code but i'd like to know that is it kind of revamping my code to HTML5, CSS3 & JQuery 1.9 make it work.. instead of relying on meta tag. 

If enhancing works then can i know few tips or references to kick start the changes so that Webpages will work in all versions of  > 9, right now 11 is my target..

Comment: The `x-ua-compatible` tag/header *is a reliable approach*. It just shouldn't be seen as a *long-term solution*. I would use the meta tag (or header) for now, and slowly work on bringing the app current. A lot has changed between IE 7 and 11.